# What is the best way to represent characters in C?

Tags: c, char, character, c99

I know that a `char` is allowed to be signed or unsigned depending on the implementation. This doesn't really bother me if all I want to do is manipulate bytes. (In fact, I don't think of the `char` datatype as a character, but a byte).

But, if I understand, string literals are `signed char`s (actually they're not, but see the update below), and the function fgetc() returns `unsigned char`s casted into `int`. So if I want to manipulate characters, is it preferred style to use signed, unsigned, or ambiguous characters? Why does reading characters from a file have a different convention than literals?

I ask because I have some code in c that does string comparison between string literals and the contents of files, but having a `signed char *` vs `unsigned char *` might really make my code error prone.

**Update 1**

Ok as a few people pointed out (in answers and comments) string literals are in fact `char` arrays, not `signed char` arrays. That means I really *should* use `char *` for string literals, and not think about whether they are signed or unsigned. This makes me perfectly happy (until I have to start making conversion/comparisons with unsigned chars).

However the important question remains, how do I read characters from a file, and compare them to a string literal. The crux of which is the conversion from the `int` read using fgetc(), which explicitly reads an `unsigned char` from the file, to the `char` type, which is allowed to be either signed or unsigned.

Allow me to provide a more detailed example.

```
int main(void)
{
    FILE *someFile = fopen("ThePathToSomeRealFile.html", "r");
    assert(someFile);

    char substringFromFile[25];
    memset((void*)substringFromFile,0,sizeof(substringFromFile));

    //Alright, the real example is to read the first few characters from the file
    //And then compare them to the string I expect
    const char *expectedString = "<!DOCTYPE";

    for( int counter = 0; counter < sizeof(expectedString)/sizeof(*expectedString); ++counter )
    {
        //Read it as an integer, because the function returns an `int`
        const int oneCharacter = fgetc(someFile);
        if( ferror(someFile) )
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        if( int == EOF || feof(someFile) )
            break;

        assert(counter < sizeof(substringFromFile)/sizeof(*substringFromFile));

        //HERE IS THE PROBLEM:
        //I know the data contained in oneCharacter must be an unsigned char
        //Therefore, this is valid
        const unsigned char uChar = (const unsigned char)oneCharacter;
        //But then how do I assign it to the char?
        substringFromFile[counter] = (char)oneCharacter;
    }

    //and ultimately here's my goal
    int headerIsCorrect = strncmp(substringFromFile, expectedString, 9);

    if(headerIsCorrect != 0)
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    //else
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Essentially, I know my fgetc() function is returning something that (after some error checking) is code-able as an `unsigned char`. I know that `char` may or may not be an `unsigned char`. That means, depending on the implementation of the c standard, doing a cast to `char` will involve *no* reinterpretation. However, in the case that the system is implemented with a signed `char`, I have to worry about values that can be coded by an `unsigned char` that aren't code-able by `char` (i.e. those values between (INT8_MAX UINT8_MAX]).

tl;dr

The question is this, should I (1) copy their underlying data read by fgetc() (by casting pointers - don't worry, I know how to do that), or (2) cast down from `unsigned char` to `char` (which is only safe if I know that the values can't exceed INT8_MAX, or those values can be ignored for whatever reason)?

Comment: Its not about if is allowed or not for char to be signed or unsigned is just because the standard does not specify if plain char is signed or unsigned.

If you start using unsigned char* for strings then, as you have found, you
will merrily break all the calls to string library functions. This can be
patched up by a cast, but the real answer is not to do that in the first
place.

Answer (score 1):

The historical reasons are (as I've been told, I don't have a reference) that the `char` type was poorly specified from the beginning.

Some implementations used "consistent integer types" where `char`, `short`, `int` and so on were all signed by default. This makes sense because it makes the types consistent with each other.

Other implementations used unsigned for character, since there never existed any symbol tables with negative indices (that would be stupid) and since they saw a need for more than 128 characters (a very valid concern).

By the time C got standardized properly, it was too late to change this, too many different compilers and programs written for them were already out on the market. So the signedness of `char` was made implementation-defined, for backwards compatibility reasons.

The signedness of `char` does not matter if you only use it to store characters/strings. It only matters when you decide to involve the `char` type in arithmetic expressions or use it to store integer values - this is a very bad idea.

- For characters/string, always use `char` (or wchar_t).
- For any other form of 1 byte large data, always use `uint8_t` or `int8_t`.

---

> But, if I understand, string literals are signed char

No, string literals are `char` arrays.

> the function fgetc() returns unsigned chars casted into int

No, it returns a `char` converted to an `int`. It is `int` because the return type may contain `EOF`, which is an integer constant and not a character constant.

> having a signed char * vs unsigned char * might really make my code error prone.

No, not really. Formally, this rule from the standard applies:

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the
>   resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined. Otherwise, when converted back again, the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.

There exists no case where casting from pointer to signed char to pointer to unsigned char or vice versa, would cause any alignment issues or other issues.

Comment: `No, it returns a char converted to an int.`, wouldn't that imply sign extension, which would break programs? (Small [counter-example](http://ideone.com/b1JC7Y).)

Comment: According to the POSIX user manual (http://www.unix.com/man-page/POSIX/3posix/fgetc/), "If  the end-of-file indicator for the input stream pointed to by stream is not set and a next byte is present, the fgetc() function shall obtain the next byte as an unsigned char converted to an int". That means it doesn't return a `char` it returns an `unsigned char`, hence my question

Comment: And the question is actually not how to cast my pointer and use it, but whether casting to unsigned char * to read from a file, when my underlying char is signed (or potentially unsigned) might lead to a misinterpretation of data. If I want to compare characters in a file to characters in a string literal, should I cast pointers or values when I read from fgetc into my char * array?

Comment: @xaviersjs Ah yeah you are correct. The text you cite is actually taken straight from the C standard. Still, conversions from (possibly signed) char to unsigned char are perfectly safe. It is preferred to cast values instead of pointers, but in this specific case it shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Lundin, the conversion is the opposite, from unsigned char (coded in an `int`) to `char` (signed/unsigned, we don't know). I updated the question to try and better address this, but there are values that can be exclusively coded by one and not the other (signed/unsigned char)

Answer (score 1):

> I know that a char is allowed to be signed or unsigned depending on the implementation. This doesn't really bother me if all I want to do is manipulate bytes.

If you're going to do comparison or assign `char` to other integer types, it should bother you.

> But, if I understand, string literals are signed chars

They are of type `char[]`, so if `char` === `unsigned char`, all string literals are `unsigned char[]`.

> the function fgetc() returns unsigned chars casted into int.

That's correct and is required to omit undesired sign extension.

> So if I want to manipulate characters, is it preferred style to use signed, unsigned, or ambiguous characters?

For portability I'd advise to follow practice adapted by various libc implementations: use `char`, but before processing cast to `unsigned char` (`char*` to `unsigned char*`). This way implicit integer promotions won't turn characters in the range `0x80` -- `0xff` into negative numbers of wider types.

In short: `(signed char)a < (signed char)b` is NOT always equivalent to `(unsigned char)a < (unsigned char)b`. Here is an [example](http://ideone.com/THuIQQ).

> Why does reading characters from a file have a different convention than literals?

`getc()` needs a way to return `EOF` such that it couldn't be confused with any real `char`.

Comment: `If you're going to do comparison of assign char to other integer types, it should bother you.` It does bother me. That's why I'm asking the question. `fgetc()` returns an `int`, hence I need to know how to convert. Either I have to specify an `unsigned char *` somewhere and cast as an `unsigned char`, or I can potentially truncate by casting to `char` (which may or may not truncate, depending on the compiler)

Comment: @xaviersjs, downcasts are safe in this case. If `fgetc()` returns `EOF`, you don't store it in `char`, otherwise it's perfectly fine to use either of `signed char`, `char` or `unsigned char` because truncation does not involve additional implicit actions except the loss of higher bits, which in this case are all zeros, so no loss.